# My AdListener is displaying some error lines in the code

Tags: flutter, dart, admob, ads

```
final AdListener listener = AdListener(
    onAdloaded: (ad) {
      print('ad loaded');
    },
    onAdFailedToLoad: (ad, error) {
      ad.dispose();
    },
);
```

the adlistener on this code is not working

Answer (score 2):

```
final BannerAdListener listener = BannerAdListener(
    onAdLoaded: (ad) {
      print('ad loaded');
    },
    onAdFailedToLoad: (ad, error) {
      ad.dispose();
    },
  );
```

You need to specify which ad format you're using at the function.